# Tensile Load a load that stretches or pulls the body or structure along its length

Tags: tikz-pic

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw[thick] (0,0) -- (4,0); % rod
\draw[->,>=stealth] (0,0) -- (-1,0) node[left] {$P$}; % left force
\draw[->,>=stealth] (4,0) -- (5,0) node[right] {$P$}; % right force
\node[below] at (2,0) {Tensile load};
\end{tikzpicture}
```

Comment: Welcome. // 1. What is your question? 2. Please add what‘s missing to compile when copied. 3. May be you can add a screenshot to your question?